# cmake always use my pc installed library instead of my target path

Tags: cmake, mips

I get a project that was built for x86, and I am trying to make it work with mips. But I encounter problem when modifying the CMakelists.txt.

So here is the problem, the following code always use my PC's x86 library:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBCRYPTO REQUIRED libcrypto)
IF(LIBCRYPTO_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBCRYPTO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIBCRYPTO_LIB_DIRS})
ENDIF(LIBCRYPTO_FOUND)
```

I googled and found they always use system library first and can use *find_package* with *NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH* flag. But its not working and give me the following message. I don't know what its talking about..

```
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libcrypto" with
  any of the following names:

    libcryptoConfig.cmake
    libcrypto-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libcrypto" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libcrypto_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libcrypto" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

My question is how to properly link a library to the path I assigned to and works like original piece of code?

Comment: `I get a project that was built for x86, and I am trying to make it work with mips.` - Does it mean, that you are **cross-compiling** you project on x86(as host) for MIPS(as target)? If so, show your *toolchain file*. Approaches for find a library with `PkgConfig` CMake module and `find_package` command are independent. So, firstly shoose the one you want to follow. The meaning of the error message you get is common for all packages: you should either have `libcryptoConfig.cmake` file (according to googling results, it is absent for `libcrypto`), or have `Findlibcrypto.cmake`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks so much for your reply. Yes, I am cross-compiling on x86(as host) for MIPS(as target). I get a /lib folder under my toolchain. I guess I don't need PkgConfig since its mips? And what I don't understand about error message is that, all library is some_lib.so or some_lib.a format, why I need something like some_lib.cmake? Should I write for every packets？That will be too hard..

Comment: `find_package` uses the project-specific `.cmake` scripts. Either `*Config.cmake`, which should be provided by (installed with) the project  itself, or `Find*.cmake`, which is shipped with CMake or can be copied from the net. These scripts collect the project's files, needed for use the project: include directories, libraries, additional compiler flags and so on. `PkgConfig` uses `.pc` file which describes the same projet's properties. If you think the library is installed *system-wide*, just link with `libcrypto`: there is no needs to search the library with `find_package` or `pkg-config`.

Comment: Don't spam tags. This appears not to be related to C.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev, thanks for your valuable suggestions. Could u please provide a example about directly assign a path of the library? I tried      `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${LIBCRYPTO_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${LIBCRYPTO_LIB_DIRS}) set(${LIBCRYPTO_LIBRARIES} /home/michael/sdk/toolchain/msdk/lib/libcrypt.so)`. Its not working...

Comment: You forget to **link** with the library: `target_link_libraries(<your-target> ${LIBCRYPTO_LIBRARIES})`.